# asp Button is not working after I click on Export to Excel button of RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, button, export-to-excel, radgrid

There is a `RadGrid` with `Export to Excel` button in it. And there is a asp `Button` along with 2 `DropDowns` outside of RadGrid, in one of the web page in my Web Application.

2 `DropDowns` are used to filter the records of `RadGrid` on click of asp `Button`.

**HTML code**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server" Width="207px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server" Width="207px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Generate" Width="80px" />

 <telerik:RadGrid ID="GridReport" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowGroupPanel="True"
   CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Skin="Outlook" DataSourceID="odsMonthlyStatusReport" OnItemDataBound="GridReport_ItemDataBound">

       <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True" />
       <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false"></GroupingSettings>
       <MasterTableView AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AllowMultiColumnSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
         CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="RequestID" EnableGroupsExpandAll="true" GroupLoadMode="Client" PageSize="50">

         <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" ShowExportToExcelButton="true" />
         <SortExpressions>
           <telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="RequisitionNo" SortOrder="Descending" />
         </SortExpressions>
         <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" Position="Bottom" PageSizes="50,100,150,200" />

            <Columns>
               // all columns code
            </Columns>
       </MasterTableView>
       <ExportSettings SuppressColumnDataFormatStrings="True" IgnorePaging="True" ExportOnlyData="True" Excel-Format="ExcelML" OpenInNewWindow="True" FileName="eAP_Report_MonthlyStatus" Excel-FileExtension="xls"></ExportSettings>
 </telerik:RadGrid>
```

All working fine except that, after I click on `Export to Excel` button of `RadGrid` and then if I click on asp button ("Generate"), it does not work at all. i.e, asp Button will work before I click on `Export to Excel` but it wont work after I click on `Export to Excel`

Please let me know why this issue had occur and what could be the possible solution for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot for the solution, Finally I fixed it!

I had to implement the 3rd workaround in below link:

http://www.faisalmb.com/post/Controls-not-functional-after-Export-to-Excel-or-Export-to-PDF-of-Telerik-in-Sharepoint-Application-page.aspx

Here it is just to make life simpler; Add the following script to your webpart / custom control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                         
   //sharepoint postback to work after clicking on telerik export to pdf
   if (typeof (_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames) != 'undefined' && _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames != null) {
        _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("supressSubmitWraper");
     }

   function supressSubmitWraper() {
        _spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper = true;
     }                      
</script>
```

**NOTE:** This issue occurs when using Sharepoint environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
You do not need code behind to use the embedded export feature of the radgrid. Try to add the page settings and may be also the pdf to check if it works with pdf:

<ExportSettings ExportOnlyData="True" IgnorePaging="True">
  <Pdf PageWidth="210mm" PageHeight="297mm" PaperSize="A4"></Pdf>
  <Excel Format="ExcelML" />
</ExportSettings>
 if still not working then I think you are using AJAX enabled the grid, so it cannot send the file. Take a look here to see if this is the case and how to fix it: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-export-with-ajax-enabled.html
```

then try this link might be helpful to you
 http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/14-06-27/new-export-and-import-capabilities-for-asp-net-ajax-suite.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But please re-view my question one more time as am having an issue. I am not using code behind for export feture in RadGrid, rather I did `<ExportSettings ... >` HTML code in RadGrid. Also, I checked the suggested link but still could not resolved my issue. Please let me know the reason of issue and how to solve it. I had pasted whole HTML code in my posted question